# Do was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am running a batch file script with the following code,

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String2Search%">null && (
    Set String2=1
        )


for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String3Search%">null && (
     Set String3=0
        )



for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String4Search%">null && (
    Set String4=0
        )
```

However, it is coming back with the error

> "do was unexpected at this time."

The code works as expected to this point. Where am i going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to tell when you do not tell us the value of `index`... I cannot believe the code works as expected (unless you want it to return an error)... Anyway, you have unbalanced parentheses...

Comment: @aschipfl The value of index is a list of websites within IE. If i run the following command it works without hiccups, for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
    echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String2Search%">nul && (
 Call :Kill "!ProcessName!"
        )

Comment: `index` should contain an integer only! place `echo %index%` before your `for /L` loops to check its actual value... Still you have unbalanced `(`/`)`...

Comment: @aschipfl apologies, i meant it contains the number of websites within IE. So running that command returns 3.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses. You are never closing the for command.

Comment: By the way, the Null device in Windows is called `nul` but not `null`...

Answer (score 0):

As @aschipfl & @Squashman pointed out, my issue is relating to an unbalanced parenthesis. Silly mistake, but it corrected my issue.

So the code now looks like this,

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String2Search%">nul && (
     Set String2=1
         ))


for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String3Search%">nul && (
      Set String3=0
        ))



for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String4Search%">nul && (
    Set String4=0
        ))
```

Comment: Are you aware that using `findstr` instead of `find` gives the ability to match all of your strings in one command? Parsing them for specific use may take a little work, but one `for /L` loop with one `findstr` could be more efficient. Take a look at its usage by entering `findstr /?` at the Command Prompt.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for this, will take a look.